# SSRS "Go to report" in linked reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report A that has an action to redirect to report B for additional details

This works

I then have 2 reports in another folder linked from A and B (lets call them A1 and B1)

I am specifying the link as "B"  not something like "/myfolder/B"

Still it looks like A1 links to B and not B1.

Is there any way to force report paths to be selected from the local path of the report, and not from the parent report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an expression like:

```
=Globals!ReportFolder+"B1"
```

- as the specified Go To Report in the action options.

Comment: Thank you, that was it
Just to be exact, the correct syntax would be 
=Globals!ReportFolder & "/B1"